# How to see the items of datagrid view in visual studio 2013 c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I want to know how to see the datagrid view row elements(data) in visual studio 2013 during debugging it.
Thankyou!

Comment: Add a Watch to dgv.Rows during debugging. It will persist between runs. Then go can drill into the cells.. For a specific Cell you can add a Watch to dgc[col,row]..